# Inverse relation of hasManyThrough in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, has-many-through

Which is the inverse relation of hasManyThrough in Laravel?

es
A->B->C

in class A:
return $this->hasManyThrough('C','B');

in class C:
which is the relation to return A objects?

thank you

Comment: `$c_instance->b->a` surely?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it really exists the literal "belongsToManyThrough" as i tried it and i am using Laravel 5.8. It didn't work. 
The best thing still would be 
`C->B->A->property`